# How to set Windows environment variable from Tcl script

Tags: windows, tcl, environment-variables

I have a Tcl script which generates some value which I like to store in a Windows environment variable. I know that this cannot be done directly from within my script.

What I am planning to do is to output the value to stderr:

```
puts stderr $var
```

How do I use the stderr channel to set a environment variable in the calling batch file?

Is there a more convenient way to set a environment variable from a Tcl script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use the Tcl script to write a batch file with a known name that contains the environment variable setting, say `env.bat`:

```
set f [open env.bat w]
puts $f "SET FOO=BAR"
close $f
```

Then you can make your *real* batch file just `CALL` that to get the environment variable definition from it:

```
CALL env.bat
```

This is the method that is going to be easiest to make work in a way that is non-surprising. It's also going to be pretty easy to debug, since you can always look at `env.bat` in a text editor and figure out if the things in it are sensible. (I'm assuming that everything is run in the same directory and that the code has permission to write there; that's *definitely* the easiest way to do it. It's possible to write a temporary file somewhere else and pass the name around, but that's rather more complex to make function correctly.)

Comment: Thanks Donal, your suggestion provides a generic solution for my issue. However, in my particular case, I only have a limited number of possible return values, so i decided to return from Tcl using the exit command and then evaluate the ERRORLEVEL in the caller batch file. Works fine!